# In Symfony2 where is the correct place to store an app wide parameter?

Tags: php, parameters, symfony

I'd like to store a few application specific values for example:

- a default Id number for a particular user choice if it's not set yet
- keys/tokens/secrets for various services API's like facebook or flickr

Closest I've found so far is http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html#configuration

If I used `app/config/parameters.ini` it would look like:

```
[flickr]
    callbackUrl = http://example.com/approve
    requestTokenUrl = http://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/request_token
    consumerKey = 123a1237a29b123a5541232e0279123

[app]
    default_layout = 2
```

these should be available in different bundles and also in templates

Answer (score 6):

> these should be available in different bundles and also in templates

They are. As long as you can access the container, you can access the parameters. From the docs you linked to:
`$container->getParameter('acme_hello.email.from');`

I think there's an error in your `parameters.ini` example. 'flickr' and 'app' shouldn't be wrapped in brackets. Also, the first element of parameters.ini should be `[parameters]`.

Personally, I like using an `app.yml` file because I'm used to using it in Symfony 1.x projects (and because I don't see the reason for using an .ini file.). You can create `app/config/app.yml` and import it into your `app/config/config.yml` file like this:

```
imports:
    - { resource: app.yml }
```

Your app.yml would look like this:

```
parameters:
  flickr:
    callbackUrl:     http://example.com/approve
    requestTokenUrl: http://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/request_token
    consumerKey:     123a1237a29b123a5541232e0279123

  app:
    default_layout:  2
```

And this is how you would access data:
`$container->getParameter('flickr.callbackUrl');`

A third option is to define your parameters directly in `app/config/config.yml`. The code would be exactly the same as my example for `app/config/app.yml`. I don't recommend doing this though because `app/config/config.yml` can get pretty filled up with bundle configuration parameters, and I think it's cleaner to keep your own app params in a separate file. But of course, it's all up to you.

Comment: I like your second method but I can't get it working. Is $container->getParameter() available in any controller? Should it be $this->container... ?

Comment: also, should default_layout = 2 be default_layout: 2 ?

Comment: @ed209: yes it should, this is yml. I think that in a controller, you can do this : `$this->getContainer()` to get the container.

Comment: @greg0ire $this->getContainer() doesn't work. What has worked is using $this->container->getParameter('default_layout') where default_layout is in parameters.ini but I'd rather use the .yml method

Comment: @Arms I don't think you can go deeper than one level in app.yml as you did above - if using the getParameter() method

Comment: This call `$container->getParameter('flickr.callbackUrl');` does not work when trying to access parameter on the 2nd level. Need to do: `$flickr_assoc = $container->getParameter('flickr'); $clbckUrl = $flickr_assoc['callbackUrl'];`